# How do i limit the number of event subscriptions when raised by an event aggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I need to limit the number of subscriptions for an event raised using event aggregator , How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check `InvocationList.Count` in `add` method of your event.

Something like this:

```
private EventHandler MyEventDel;       


   public event EventHandler ExplicitEvent
    {
        add
        {
            if (MyEventDel.GetInvocationList().Count() < 10)
            {
                MyEventDel+= value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            MyEventDel-= value;
        }
    }
```